# Flash overlapping an html div

Tags: flash, layout, overlap

I have a weather widget that is flash and expandable. one of the issues i had is when I expand the widget, it wouldn't expand passed the flash container size, so most of the content is cut up. I increased the size of the flash container and that worked. The problem is that the I have another facebook widget that is below the weather widget and that got pushed a lot. I moved the facebook widget up with a negative margin and now they are aligned fine. BUT i can't interact with the facebook widget. and I think the reason is that it is actually behind the flash container. it works fine on ie but i am trying to get it to work on chrome. I have changed the z-index to make the facebook widget on top of the flash, but the flash started to appear behind the facebook now. you can see it live on http://www.tennis-lounge.com/tennisdev/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to change the wmode property of your flash. http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141 or http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html have a good explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
wmode='transparent'
```

Should help, as it would enable you to interact with content below the flash layer.